# how to convert the type of each element in a list to a list in python

Tags: python, list

How can I change the list below :

`list1 = ['A','B,'C]`

to this :

`list1 = [['A'],['B'],['C']]`
I don't want to do this manually because elements are too many.

Comment: `list1 = [[i] for i in list1]`

Comment: What did you try? What did not work? Why ask? use a simple loop to put things into a new list and put each element into its own list.,....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new_list = []
for i in list1:
    new_list.append([i])
```

Should do the trick, but there are other ways.

Answer (score 3):

Iterate on the list and wraph each item in a list itself

```
list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
list1 = [[i] for i in list1]
print(list1)  # [['A'], ['B'], ['C']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The most pythonic way to do it in my opinion is:

```py
list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
list1 = list(map(lambda e: [e], list1))
print(list1)  # [['A'], ['B'], ['C']]
```